# Converting days in pandas dataframe to other categories

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
                 country      Duration
0               Afghanistan   0 days
1               Afghanistan   4 days
2               Afghanistan   0 days
3               Afghanistan   22 days
4               Afghanistan   6 days
                     ...      ...
316813  Zimbabwe (Rhodesia)   36 days
316814  Zimbabwe (Rhodesia)   6 days
316815  Zimbabwe (Rhodesia)   223 days
316816  Zimbabwe (Rhodesia)   6 days
316817  Zimbabwe (Rhodesia)   0 days
```

I would like to convert the Duration column into the following categories:
`< 1 week, 1-4 weeks, 1-3 months, 3-6 months, 6-9 months, 9-12 months`

How do i achieve that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Month` is not really a valid time interval, because months have different day length. That said, you can convert the `Duration` column to `TimeDelta` and then `pd.cut`:

```
pd.cut(pd.to_timedelta(df['Duration']),
       bins=pd.to_timedelta([0, '1W', '30D', '90D', '180D', '270D', '365D', '36500D']),
       include_lowest=True,
       labels=['< 1 week', '1-4 weeks', '1-3 months', '3-6 months', '6-9 months', '9-12 months', '> 12 months']
      )
```

Output:

```
0           < 1 week
1           < 1 week
2           < 1 week
3          1-4 weeks
4           < 1 week
...              NaN
316813    1-3 months
316814      < 1 week
316815    6-9 months
316816      < 1 week
316817      < 1 week
Name: Duration, dtype: category
Categories (7, object): ['< 1 week' < '1-4 weeks' < '1-3 months' < '3-6 months' < '6-9 months' < '9-12 months' < '> 12 months']
```